# Trouble finding the minimum and maximum of an array value - C++

Tags: c++

here is the question

> 1. Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of kilometres run by 10
>    different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10). Use an array to save the input
> 2. Once the data has been entered, the program must analyse the data and output
>    which person run the most kilometres.
> 3. Modify the program so that it also shows which person run the least number of
>    kilometres.

I think I have the algorithm in place based on my code. but the challenge I have is that it returns weird values that obviously never existed in the array.

this is an example of the final answer

```
how many kilometre did Person 1 run ?
1

how many kilometre did Person 2 run ?
2

how many kilometre did Person 3 run ?
3

how many kilometre did Person 4 run ?
4

how many kilometre did Person 5 run ?
5

how many kilometre did Person 6 run ?
6

how many kilometre did Person 7 run ?
7

how many kilometre did Person 8 run ?
8

how many kilometre did Person 9 run ?
9

how many kilometre did Person 10 run ?
10

The Person with the longest distance is Person 10 and he / she covered a distance of 10 km

The Person with the shortest distance is Person 32767 and he / she covered a distance of 10 km
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class kilometer_sort
{
    // This method / function helps collect
    // all user input of all distance ran by
    // every persons 1-10
public:
    void collect_user_input()
    {
        int no_of_persons = 10;
        int array_of_persons_speed[no_of_persons];
        int person_kilometre;
        for (int b = 0; b < no_of_persons; b++)
        {
            cout << "how many kilometre did Person " << b + 1 << " run ?\n";
            cin >> person_kilometre;
            array_of_persons_speed[b] = person_kilometre;
        }

        check_for_longest_distance(no_of_persons, array_of_persons_speed);
        check_for_shortest_distance(no_of_persons, array_of_persons_speed);
    }

    int person_with_longest_distance_array_index, person_with_shortest_distance_array_index;

public:
    void check_for_longest_distance(int n, int array_of_persons_speed[])
    {
        int highest_no;
        int longest_dist;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (array_of_persons_speed[i] > array_of_persons_speed[0])
            {
                longest_dist = array_of_persons_speed[i];
                person_with_longest_distance_array_index = i;
            }
        }

        cout << "The Person with the longest distance is Person "
             << person_with_longest_distance_array_index + 1
             << " and he / she covered a distance of "
             << longest_dist
             << " km\n\n";
    }

public:
    void check_for_shortest_distance(int n, int array_of_persons_speed[])
    {
        int highest_no;
        int shortest_distance;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (array_of_persons_speed[i] < array_of_persons_speed[0])
            {
                shortest_distance = array_of_persons_speed[i];
                person_with_shortest_distance_array_index = i;
            }
        }

        cout << "The Person with the shortest distance is Person "
             << person_with_shortest_distance_array_index + 1
             << " and he / she covered a distance of "
             << shortest_distance
             << " km\n\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Instantiate Class that sort distance
    kilometer_sort ks;

    ks.collect_user_input();

    return false;
}
```

I will appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Is `if(array_of_persons_speed[i] < array_of_persons_speed[0])` really the comparison you want to be making in `check_for_shortest_distance`? What will happen in your code if the person who ran the shortest distance is the first person in the array, i.e. `person_with_shortest_distance_array_index` is supposed to be 0? This seems like a prime candidate for stepping through your code with a debugger and seeing when values stop behaving the way you expect them to.

Comment: Note that VLA is not valid in C++ - `int array_of_persons_speed[no_of_persons];`

Comment: The question doesn't say what should happen if 2 people ran the same distance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take care of your internal variable denoting max/min amount as follows:

```
public:
    void check_for_longest_distance(int n, int array_of_persons_speed[])
    {
        int longest_dist = array_of_persons_speed[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (array_of_persons_speed[i] > longest_dist)
            {
                longest_dist = array_of_persons_speed[i];
                person_with_longest_distance_array_index = i;
            }
        }

        cout << "The Person with the longest distance is Person "
             << person_with_longest_distance_array_index + 1
             << " and he / she covered a distance of "
             << longest_dist
             << " km\n\n";
    }

    void check_for_shortest_distance(int n, int array_of_persons_speed[])
    {
        int shortest_distance = array_of_persons_speed[0]
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (array_of_persons_speed[i] < shortest_distance)
            {
                shortest_distance = array_of_persons_speed[i];
                person_with_shortest_distance_array_index = i;
            }
        }

        cout << "The Person with the shortest distance is Person "
             << person_with_shortest_distance_array_index + 1
             << " and he / she covered a distance of "
             << shortest_distance
             << " km\n\n";
    }
```

Comment: I just want to note that your question doesn't relate to sorting at all.

Comment: thank you @Mohammed Deifallah, your solution helps in getting the exact distance.. but still, have one issue left, it is with the value of the `person_with_shortest_distance_array_index + 1`  and  `person_with_longest_distance_array_index + 1`, they are still returning some odd values like `32768` which is supposed to be an array index value and my array is not more than 10 properties. kindly help look into that. thanks

Comment: This happens in case the returnee value us the first index because this variable is not initialized. You need to initialize it with 0 at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of this line is never true for your inputs:

```
if (array_of_persons_speed[i] < array_of_persons_speed[0])
```

As a result the person_with_shortest_distance_array_index is never set.

So the value you are outputting is the contents of an uninitialized value (plus one)

You could try using std::max_element and std::min_element or get both at the same time with std::minmax_element instead.